# Converting Flash based games to Apk's

Tags: android, flash, import, apk

I have been developing flash games for a short while now and have gotten,to an extent,the hang of it.I was wondering if there is a way to port these games to Android?
Keep in mind that I am relatively new to the programming thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course yes. You can create a new mobile project in flashDevelop or flashBuilder, put all the libraries and classes to a new project, check out the pathes and compile. Of course, if you game is platformer with control from the keyboard, you will need to add buttons directly on the screen or other means of control character. Must take into account the nuances of devices, screen sizes, management, and the performance